# Unusual behaviour of dismissViewController in ios7 and ios9+

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I am working on an app. In some particular stage of the app, I am dismissing ViewController and creating a new one. I use the following to dismiss,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

It is working fine with ios9+ devices. But app is crashing in ios7 devices. I replaced,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

then it work fine in all version devices. Can anyone tell, why the app crashed in ios7 device previously and Why it run perfectly in ios9+ devices?

Comment: can you show the crash report

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=...). But no crash in ios9+ devices, on same code.

Comment: Can you please share your complete function's code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to Memory Management.

The solution is to set all the delegate and data source to nil in the dealloc method.

With iOS 7 and above, it is considered good practice to set delegates and data sources to nil, because views have a longer lifespan than their view controllers and try to access their delegates after these have been released.